# In the case of [i, j], [j, i] in a dataframe, how can I only get the [i, j] row in julia?

Tags: dataframe, duplicates, julia

I use Julia. I have a data frame that looks like this

| person1 | person2 | sth1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2307 | 15 | 1234 | ... |
| 58999 | 52 | 1201 | ... |
| 15 | 2307 | 67 | ... |

For the 1st row and the 3rd, the information is the same, so I want to drop the 3rd row.

I wrote a function like this, but it does not work. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

```
function dropduplicate(df)
    iter = size(df)[1]
    for i in 1:iter, j in 1:(iter-1)
        if df[i,:][8] + df[i,:][9] == df[j,:][8] + df[j,:][9]
            delete!(df, j)
            i += 1
            j += 1
        end
    end
return df2
end
```

Comment: one good way of doing this is to make sure that person1 < person2, though it doesn't appear to work in the case you have. Are you creating permutations?

Comment: Thank you Mark, I figure it out. I added a column as the sum of the 1st person and 2nd person, only keeping the unique sum.

Comment: add it as an answer Chao! :-)

Comment: @Chao Consider the case where there are two rows `3, 7, sth1_val` and `2, 8, sth1_val` both add to 10, and one row would be deleted likely undesirably using the unique sum approach.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can do it:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(p1=[1,2,3,4], p2=[3,5,1,7], id=11:14)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ p1     p2     id
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3     11
   2 │     2      5     12
   3 │     3      1     13
   4 │     4      7     14

julia> unique(df, [:p1, :p2] => ByRow(minmax))
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ p1     p2     id
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3     11
   2 │     2      5     12
   3 │     4      7     14
```

What you do is you dynamically create a column with a tuple holding min and max value from columns `:p1` and `:p2`. The nice thing about `unique` is that you do not need to materialize this column.

Comment: by materialize, you mean add it to the dataframe right? Like it is a temporary calculation you can discard?

Comment: Yes - i.e. it is not stored in the produced data frame. The contract of `unique` does not specify how the computation is actually performed. But if you ask how it is done then yes - a temporary helper vector is created currently (but it potentially might change in the future).