# In the case of [i, j, z], [j, i, z] , [i, j, x]in a dataframe, how can I only get the [i, j, z] and [i, j, x] row in julia? (further question)

Tags: dataframe, duplicates, julia, contacts

this is a follow-up question to yesterday's question: [In the case of [i, j], [j, i] in a dataframe, how can I only get the [i, j] row in julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76952252/in-the-case-of-i-j-j-i-in-a-dataframe-how-can-i-only-get-the-i-j-row)
In the case of a data frame like this

| row | p1 | p2 | s1 | t1 | s2 | t2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 355 | 210 | 66541 | 68071 | 65821 | 68071 |
| 2 | 355 | 210 | 68503 | 74299 | 68503 | 72481 |
| 3 | 210 | 355 | 68503 | 72481 | 68503 | 74299 |

For 2nd row and 3rd row, the information are the same, I only want to get one of them and the 1st row.
Following answer provided from yesterday, I used the sum of p1, p2, s1, s2, to try to get the unique.

```
unique(df, [:p1, :p2, :s1, s2] => ByRow(minmax))
```

but I got error like this

```
MethodError: no method matching sum(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Float64)
```

Comment: Can you please precisely specify what rule you want to use to decide that two rows are duplicate?

Comment: Yes, Bogumił. s1 and t1, is the value with p1 (time interval, start time and end time of the activity conducted by p1), and s2 and t2 is the value with p2. I am looking for the contact between p1 and p2. I posted my answer here, it will give you more information. BTW, I like your online tutorials about Julia DataFrame. Thank you very much!

Comment: The solution you posted below does not match your description. The two rows kept are identical (which I assume you did not want). I asked about the rule: do you want to only do matching on `:p1` and `:p2` columns, or also you want to add some condition on `:s1` and `:s2` columns? (or maybe also on `:t1` and `:t2` columns - although I do not see that you wanted to use them in your original question).

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the table. Yes, I also want to pair with s1, t1, s2, t2.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I understand you additionally want to reorder-columns. There are several ways how this can be done but I think the simplest would be:

```
sort_row(p1, p2, s1, t1, s2, t2) =
    if p1 < p2
        (p1, p2, s1, t1, s2, t2)
    else
        (p2, p1, s2, t2, s1, t1)
    end
unique(select(df, All() => ByRow(sort_row) => identity), [:p1, :p2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Julia. I wrote a function, it is a stupid method but finally solved the problem.

```
d = DataFrame(p1 = [1, 2, 2], p2 = [2, 1, 1], s1 = [9, 3, 6], t1 = [8, 9, 4], s2 = [3, 9, 8], t2 = [9, 8, 9], pt = ["pt_186", "pt_186", "pt_pt_N11"])

function filterduplicate(df)
iter = size(df)[1]
p1 = Vector{Int64}()
p2 = Vector{Int64}()
s1 = Vector{Float64}()
t1 = Vector{Float64}()
s2 = Vector{Float64}()
t2 = Vector{Float64}()
pt = Vector{String31}() 
    for i in 1:iter
        if df[i,:][1] > df[i,:][2]
            push!(p1, df[i,:][2])
            push!(p2, df[i,:][1])
            push!(s1, df[i,:][5])
            push!(t1, df[i,:][6])
            push!(s2, df[i,:][3])
            push!(t2, df[i,:][4])
            push!(pt, df[i, :][7])
        else
            push!(p1, df[i,:][1])
            push!(p2, df[i,:][2])
            push!(s1, df[i,:][3])
            push!(t1, df[i,:][4])
            push!(s2, df[i,:][5])
            push!(t2, df[i,:][6])
            push!(pt, df[i, :][7])
            i += 1
        end
    end
return unique(DataFrame(p1 = p1, p2= p2, s1 = s1, t1 = t1, s2 = s2, t2 = t2, pt = pt))
end
```

Comment: Why not merge your two answers?

Comment: I am lazy.......

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the question here, a professor (Martin Kühn) helped me to work it out. So I am posting the answer also here, in case other ones also face a similar question.

Basically, the idea is to change the order of p1 and p2, if p1 is langer than p2, also other values. Then it will get this:

| row | p1 | p2 | s1 | t1 | s2 | t2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 355 | 210 | 66541 | 68071 | 65821 | 68071 |
| 2 | 355 | 210 | 68503 | 74299 | 68503 | 72481 |
| 3 | 210 | 355 | 68503 | 72481 | 68503 | 74299 |

then use the unique function to filter.

He used Python to solve it, I paste the code here.

```
df = pd.read_csv("path.csv")

indices_p2grp1 = np.where(df['p2'] < df['p1'])[0]

df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['p2', 'p1', 's2', 'e2', 's1', 'e1')
df_new[['p2', 'p1', 's2', 'e2', 's1', 'e1']] = df.iloc[indices_p2grp1].copy()
df_new = df_new[df.columns]

indices_p1gep2 = np.sort(np.array(list(set(list(range(len(df)))).difference(set(list(indices_p2grp1))))))

df_final = pd.concat([df_new, df.iloc[indices_p1gep2, :]], ignore_index=True)
```

The final table I want to get is this

| row | p1 | p2 | s1 | t1 | s2 | t2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 210 | 355 | 65821 | 68071 | 66541 | 68071 |
| 2 | 210 | 355 | 68503 | 72481 | 68503 | 74299 |